# No search result on Wiki Pages

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, search, search-results

I have created a new page in the SharePoint 2010. When I try to search the content of the page, there are no results appeared. How can I solve this issue?

[image: the result of search]

Comment: Are you the SharePoint farm admin? Is search work on other pages?

Comment: It doesnt work for other pages too.

Comment: Ask your SharePoint admin to configure search service.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you search page contents in the search center? Can you search other contents such like documents in the SharePoint? What is the type of contents you are searching for? Text or document?

To troubleshoot this issue, check things below:

1.Run a full crawl in the search service application, then search again, compare the result.

2.Check whether pages are in the crawl logs.

3.Go to admin page of search service application, check whether any error messages on it.

4.Make sure pages are published and approval.

5.Make sure pages are checked in at least one time.